# Perl allowing arrows in console menu

Tags: perl

I'am making some simple project where I want to use arrows to naviagete in console menu. I need that down and up arrows allow me to change selected menu item(I am painting menu with some colors). I dont want to confirm each arrow by enter(atm I'm using simple chops which needs enter, and I even dont know how to allow arrows for chop). I need some sort of auto detect arrows is there any nice solution for that?

Comment: "There are no arrow keys (sensu key code in terminal windows). Use cat -vet to know what sequence to expect for a key." (From http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=798213 )

Comment: Have a look at `Term::ReadKey`.

Comment: Ye I am using Term:ReadKey but after reading key I need to know how to make condition. if (readedKey == ?keyup?) { ... } if (readedKey == ?keydown?) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how to make condition. if (readedKey == ?keyup?) { ...
>   } if (readedKey == ?keydown?) { ... }

You could `use Curses`; example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Curses;
initscr; refresh;
keypad(1);  # enable arrow keys to return a single value
noecho;
print "Press Esc to end.\r\n";
while (($readedKey = getch()) ne "\e")
{
    if ($readedKey eq KEY_UP) { print "You pressed the up arrow.\r\n"; }
    elsif ($readedKey eq KEY_DOWN) { print "You pressed the down arrow.\r\n"; }
    else
    {
        ($printable = $readedKey) =~ s'[[:cntrl:]]'"^".chr(ord($&)^64)'e;
        print "You pressed the key '$printable'.\r\n";
    }
}
endwin;
```